# How to call a social login block to header login popup in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, layout, xml

I installed the social login extension, It works fine in registration page & registration page sign-in popup. But in others pages it's not displaying social logins block in sign-in popup. Here is the url for [reference](http://potboy.com.my/)

Here is the xml layout file which was working in registration page

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Webkul_SocialSignup::css/socialsignup.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Webkul\SocialSignup\Block\Active" name="socialsignup_block">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="socialsignup/sociallogin/enabled" ifvalue="1">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Webkul_SocialSignup::socialsignup/block.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Can anyone guide me how to call the social login block in popup for other pages too

Comment: What are the other pages you need to show social login block?

Answer (score 0):

I think following tutorial may help you.

https://popatkaran.wordpress.com/2016/08/17/magento-2-open-login-form-in-popup/

In this tutorial, login popup is created.